# How Do I Randomly Match Elements in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to randomly match elements of a table by some condition (1:1 and symmetric pairing, so if user x matches with user y, then user y matches with user x)

```sql
WITH tbl AS (
  SELECT 1 AS user, 'A' AS condition
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS user, 'A' AS condition
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS user, 'A' AS condition
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS user, 'B' AS condition
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS user, 'B' AS condition
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS user, 'B' AS condition
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 AS user, 'B' AS condition
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 AS user, 'B' AS condition
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 9 AS user, 'B' AS condition
)
SELECT
  user,
  condition
FROM tbl
```

How can I generate a query to:

1. randomly match all users in condition B with another user in condition B
2. do the same with condition A, but leave one condition A user unmatched because there are an odd number of users with condition A
3. identifies the unmatched user (1, 2, or 3) with a NULL match

Hypothetical result:

| user | condition | match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 3 |
| 2 | A | NULL |
| 3 | A | 1 |
| 4 | B | 7 |
| 5 | B | 9 |
| 6 | B | 8 |
| 7 | B | 4 |
| 8 | B | 6 |
| 9 | B | 5 |

Comment: please clarify / explain further `but leave one user unmatched because there are an odd number of users`! I don't see any difference in doing so for even or odd number. so please clear this. and btw, in your example match is not random but rather based on opposite  order - is it for reason? or should be really random?

Comment: ok. i see now after your recent edit

Comment: Thank you for pushing me to clarify. (1) I merely mean that we obviously cannot perfectly match everyone in condition A because there are an odd number with A, so someone will be left without a partner. (2) Indeed, that was a bad example because it gave the false appearance that I just wanted a reverse-sorted pairing. I added a couple more example users to make the random sampling look more random.

Comment: sure, looks good and clear to me now :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
create temp table temp as 
select _0 as user, condition, _1 as match from (
  select user, condition, div(offset, 2) grp, mod(offset, 2) pos
  from (
    select condition, array_agg(user order by rand()) users
    from your_table
    group by condition
  ), unnest(users) user with offset
)
pivot (any_value(user) for pos in (0,1));

select * from (
  select * from temp union all
  select match, condition, user from temp 
)
where not user is null;
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

As you can see above solution requires scripting to be involved - so below is slightly refactored version that allows you to achive same result with just one "simple" query

```
select * from (
  select if(grp < 0, _0, _1) as user, condition, if(grp < 0, _1, _0) as match from (
    select user, condition, grp, mod(offset, 2) pos
    from (
      select condition, array_agg(user order by rand()) users
      from your_table
      group by condition
    ), unnest(users) user with offset, unnest([div(offset + 2, 2), -1 * div(offset + 2, 2)]) grp
  )
  pivot (any_value(user) for pos in (0,1))
)
where not user is null
```

Comment: I love how your answers always make me learn new functions and features that I never knew about. I will work through this tonight to understand.